# SQL Server - Most Efficient Way to Replace Multiple String Patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to clean up a string field and replace a dozen different patterns.  I know you can use a nested REPLACE function, but doing that a lot is a real pain to type and makes for some very ugly code.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The nested `replace()` is possibly the fastest approach.  There are other methods, but they are probably slower for the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the nested replace . . . without nesting.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*, t_r12.col_r
from t outer apply
     (select replace(t.col, 'in1', 'out1') as col_r) t_r01 outer apply
     (select replace(t_r01.col_r, 'in2', 'out2') as col_r) t_r02 outer apply
     (select replace(t_r02.col_r, 'in3', 'out3') as col_r) t_r03 outer apply
     . . .;
```

In this context, I don't think that `outer apply` adds any (significant) overhead.  However, this does require naming all the intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a CLR procedure that uses a REGEX to do the replace.